# How do I do a group count on two fields, to summarise colour and size choices?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where each row is a person's choice of colour and size of a T-Shirt. It looks something like this:

```
┌─────────┬────────┐
│ Large   │  Red   │
│ Small   │  Blue  │
│ Medium  │  Red   │
│ Small   │  Red   │
│ Medium  │  Red   │
└─────────┴────────┘
```

I'd like to be able to summarise that in a form I can give to a supplier, ideally like this:

```
┌────────┬──────┬───┐
│ Large  │ Red  │ 1 │
│ Medium │ Red  │ 2 │
│ Small  │ Blue │ 1 │
│ Small  │ Red  │ 1 │
└────────┴──────┴───┘
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Pivot Tables which have blown my mind. Select the `Data->Pivot Table` menu, then the range your data applies to, and then the rows and columns for your dataset. Here's what my finished table looks like:

[image]